# AWS S3 permissions - error with put-bucket-acl

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I am trying to move an S3 bucket from one account (A) to another (B).
I have succeeded with that operation and remove the bucket from account A.
I am trying to move the new  bucket from account B to another bucket on account B, but learning that beside the bucket itself I have no access to the files.
After much fighting with s3 cli and its permissions I checked `s3api` commands and found out that the files (surprise surprise) still holds the old ownership.
I am trying now to change it, but came to a stand still with the `put-bucket-acl`, the JSON file isn't working for `s3api` command.
I tried running the command in debug , but didn't make too much out of it.
Anybody knows what to do ?
Maybe a better way to solve this issue ?

what I did so far:
the command:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket my-bucket  --cli-input-json file://1.json
```

(Same with put-object-acl)

1.json file:

```
"Grantee": {
"DisplayName": "account_B",
"EmailAddress": "user@mail.com",
"ID": "111111hughalphnumericnumber22222",
"Type": "CanonicalUser",
"Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
 }
```

The errors I get :

> Unknown parameter in input: "Grantee", must be one of: ACL,
>   AccessControlPolicy, Bucket, ContentMD5, GrantFullControl, GrantRead,
>   GrantReadACP, GrantWrite, GrantWriteACP Unknown parameter in input:
>   "Permission", must be one of: ACL, AccessControlPolicy, Bucket,
>   ContentMD5, GrantFullControl, GrantRead, GrantReadACP, GrantWrite,
>   GrantWriteACP

UPDATE:
AssumeRole between the 2 accounts doesn't work in my case.
cli (s3cmd,s3api) GUI (MCSTools,bucketexplorer), ACL using headers,body (Postman) did not help as well..
I'm connecting AWS support and hoping for the best.
I'll update when I have a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, AWS support came to the rescue... I'm leaving this for others to see, so they won't have to waste 2 days like I did trying to figure what the hell went wrong...

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket <bucket_on_B> --key <Key_on_B_Owned_by_A>  --profile IAM_User_A > A_to_B.json
```

apply the outcome of:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket <Bucket_on_B> --profile IAM_User_B
```

onto the json file that was created, and then run

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket <Bucket_on_B> --key <Key_on_B_Owned_by_A> --access-control-policy file://A_to_B.json --profile IAM_User_A
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `file://<myfile.json>` part.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is wrong. According [to the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html) for the `put-bucket-acl` option you can generate valid JSON template ('skeleton') using `--generate-cli-skeleton`. For example:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket BUCKETNAME --generate-cli-skeleton
```

And here is the output:

```
{
    "ACL": "", 
    "AccessControlPolicy": {
        "Grants": [
            {
                "Grantee": {
                    "DisplayName": "", 
                    "EmailAddress": "", 
                    "ID": "", 
                    "Type": "", 
                    "URI": ""
                }, 
                "Permission": ""
            }
        ], 
        "Owner": {
            "DisplayName": "", 
            "ID": ""
        }
    }, 
    "Bucket": "", 
    "ContentMD5": "", 
    "GrantFullControl": "", 
    "GrantRead": "", 
    "GrantReadACP": "", 
    "GrantWrite": "", 
    "GrantWriteACP": ""
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this option, but I'm not clear on the parameters- do I need to insert them all ? How do I get the "URI" if I don't want it to be public? where do I get the "ContentMD5"
I the "Owner" - do I insert the old owner? 
What do I do if I have a user without an email address? how to give him access?
Thanks!

Comment: There're good examples with a minimal structure at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTacl.html. You can omit `ContentMD5`. And you can omit user e-mail if you don't use `AmazonCustomerByEmail` and use `CanonicalUser` or `Group` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who's still looking to do this - OP probably looked at the right aws doc but overlooked the right command. I'm just glad I got to right command because of this stackoverflow page :)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html

^^ The json syntax with example is present there and instead of `--cli-input-json` , use `--access-control-policy`

```
{
  "Grants": [
    {
      "Grantee": {
        "DisplayName": "string",
        "EmailAddress": "string",
        "ID": "string",
        "Type": "CanonicalUser"|"AmazonCustomerByEmail"|"Group",
        "URI": "string"
      },
      "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"|"WRITE"|"WRITE_ACP"|"READ"|"READ_ACP"
    }
    ...
  ],
  "Owner": {
    "DisplayName": "string",
    "ID": "string"
  }
}
```

I had the policy as a json file and used this command it worked just fine.

`aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucketname --access-control-policy file://yourJson.json`

Also one more thing to note is that I wasn't able to add permissions along with existing ones, old acl was being overwritten. So any permission you want to add needs to be in json policy file along with existing policy. It will be easier when you use some command to describe all the ACLs first.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is the following (with example):

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucket_name --access-control-policy file://grant.json
```

grant.json file:

```
{
    "Grants": [
            {
            "Grantee": {
                "ID": "CANONICAL_ID_TO_GRANT",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "WRITE"
            },
            {
            "Grantee": {
                "ID": "CANONICAL_ID_TO_GRANT",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
            }
        ],
        "Owner": {
            "DisplayName": "example_owner",
            "ID": "CANONICAL_ID_OWNER"
        }
}
```